# How to create a counter within a counter using verilog?

Tags: counter, verilog

For a project, I need to write values to an address to display on a screen. This means I need two counters, one for the row value and one for the column value. Usually, when I work with Java, I would use nested for loops. But in Verilog, that logic isn't going to work so well. Any help to figure out how to put a counter inside of a counter?

Answer (score 0):

A set of nested counters can be implemented instead as a series of counters. You have your first counter increment as usual. Then, for some value of the first counter (perhaps when it loops back to 0), you increment the second counter.

(i.e. [0,M-1] -> [1,0], where the first counter ranges {0,M-1})